# En C#, como se la longitud máxima para crear un vector para que no sea lanzada una Excepción OutOfMemory?

Tags: c#

Buenas, el problema es el siguiente, em determinado proyecto pregunto la cantidad de elementos del arreglo al usuario advirtiendo que debe ser un entero mayor que 0 (uso int32), el problema surge en el máximo permitido, yo no le puedo advertir que es el Int32.MaxValue porque de todos modos puede lanzar una Excepción OutOfMemory estando en ese rango... Hay posibilidades de obtener la mayor longitud disponible para crear un arreglo?

Comment: pero porque no lo limitas mediante uan validacion a un valor que consideres razonable ? o sea imagina que defines 100 items maximo (es solo un ejemplo) entonces cuando el usuario ingresa un valor mayor se lo informas y le solicitas un nuevo valor. Porque complicarse con los valores maximos de las variables

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir segmentos de código donde te lanza la excepción? De igual forma, algunos valores con los que haces uso de los enteros, con esto nos daremos una idea más exacta del problema que estás presentado y habrá una solución más rápida y concreta.

Comment: Para evitarte todo eso podrías usar memoria dinámica, listas..., entonces al usuario no deberias pedirle que ingrese la cantidad de elementos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que recomendaria es que no uses ningun Array usa listas genericas para crear colecciones de objetos o valores

[List (Clase)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.90).aspx)

Con la lista no tendras problema de ningun maximo que el usuario ingrese ya que esta podra ser tan grande como memoria tengas disponible.

Lo que si vas a tener que validar es que se ingrese un valor numerico valido.

Respecto al OutOfMemory recomendaria defines una validacion y limites la cantidad de item que vas a permitir a un valor razonable que consideres para tu aplicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Yo al igual que el usuario anterior usaría colecciones genéricas, en caso de que una vez introducidos los datos solamente quisieses mostrarlos usaría IEnumerable y en otro caso usaría List. Así no deberías preocuparte por el máximo, podrías controlar mediante una variable el número de elementos que introduce el usuario, pidiéndola incluso por pantalla, y no dejar mediante código que se introduzcan más. Para controlar que los números introducidos fuesen mayor que cero, en caso de que fuesen menores lanzaría una excepción ArgumentOutOfRangeException, o alguna excepción customizada.

Comment: Recomendaria que agregaras un codigo ejemplo de lo que dices

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien a que te referías Iván con el código de ejemplo, pero he creado un pequeño programita, que controla la inserción, mediante un bucle do-while (para que no se exceda el tamaño del array y que también controle por excepción este problema, y que controle por excepción también la introducción de un número negativo.
Espero que solucione algo o aclare algunas dudas, pero es la forma que yo usaría para el control de entrada de datos en un array.

```
public class NegativeNumberException : Exception
{
    public NegativeNumberException()
    {
    }


    public NegativeNumberException(String message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public NegativeNumberException(String message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

}

public class MaxArrayLengthException : Exception
{
    public MaxArrayLengthException()
    { }

    public MaxArrayLengthException(String message) : base(message)
    { }

    public MaxArrayLengthException(String message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    { }


}



class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Int64 _maxNumber = 0; 
        Int64 _count = 0;

        String _numberExceptionMessage = "Exception: Numbers must be greater than 0";
        String _arrayExceptionMessage = "Exception: Array max length has been reached";

        List<Int64> _numberArray = new List<Int64>();

        Console.WriteLine("Insert array max length");
        _maxNumber = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

        do
        {

            if (_count + 1 > _maxNumber)
            {
                throw new MaxArrayLengthException(_arrayExceptionMessage);
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Insert new number");

                Int64 value = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());

                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new NegativeNumberException(_numberExceptionMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    _numberArray.Add(value);
                    _count++;
                }
            }
        } while (_count < _maxNumber);
      }
    }
```